# Generate image thumnbnails in OS X?

Tags: mac, images

OS X 10.6.8

I was assisting a  with their friend their Mac, I'm not sure if it was MBA or MBP, but it was a laptop.

Anyways, we were transferred dozens of images from iPhoto to another user account via cut/paste.

For some reason, we can view some, but not all of the images. We changed the permissions for the account, we can now view the images couldn't view.

The main problem: The rest of images are displaying thumbnails, except for the ones that we had add/change permissions for.

So, how can I get thumbnails to show for the images that don't currently have thumbnails?

Perhaps some kind of utility?

Comment: How did you fix the permission problem? This sounds like an ownership problem.  Did the owner of the *destination* directory perform the paste?

Comment: Option Command I. That brought up the properties/permissions Window and went with that. The images we fixed permissions for are viewable. But still no thumbnials.

Comment: If it were me, and the directory was *in my home directory*, I'd do a `chown -R my_username:staff ./` from the top level of the "troublesome" directories just to rule out a potential ownership problem.